# Agregar un botón de eliminar a tabla dinamica Js

Tags: javascript, html, json

Estoy llenando una tabla dinamica con un arreglo, pero no logro agregar el boton de eliminar en otra culumna de la tabla

mi arreglo

```
const response =  [
   "elemento1",
   "elemento2"];
```

Así lleno la tabla

```
 load("files", function (response) {
    
            var botones = document.getElementsByClassName('eliminaFile');
        
            multipleFileUploadError.style.display = "none";
            var content = "<p>Archivos Cargados: </p>";
        
        
            response.forEach((file, index) => rollCall(file, index));
        
            response.sort();
        
            let table = document.getElementById("tabla");
        //aquí recorro mi arreglo
            for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {

        //aquí lleno la primer columna
                table.innerHTML += "<tr><td><a href='" + response[i] + "' target='_blank'>" response[i]+ "</a></td></tr>";
        
//aqui intento crear la otra columna con el botón eliminar
        // content += "<p>Descargar Archivo : <a href='" + response[i] + "' target='_blank'>" + response[i] + "</a></p>" + "<input class='eliminaFile' type='button' id='" + response[i] + "' value='Eliminar'>";
    
            }
            multipleFileUploadSuccess.innerHTML = content;
            multipleFileUploadSuccess.style.display = "block";
        });
```

este es el html de la tabla

```
<table class="demo">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Archivo</th>
                        <th>Acciones</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="cuerpoTabla">
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Quiero agregar el boton de eliminar y que se elimine el elemento que se selecciono pero no lo logro

Comment: se formateó medio raro tu ppregunta, puedes checar para que se muestren bien tus archivos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongo que esto es lo que buscas

```
load("files", function (response) {
    multipleFileUploadError.style.display = "none";
    var content = "<p>Archivos Cargados: </p>";
    response.sort();

    let table = document.getElementById("tabla");

    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        rollCall(response[i], i)

        table.innerHTML += `<tr>
            <td><a href="${response[i]}" target="_blank">${response[i]}</a></td>
            <td><input class='eliminaFile' onclick="eliminar('${response[i]}',${i})" type='button' id='${response[i]}' value='Eliminar'></td>
        </tr>`;
    }
    multipleFileUploadSuccess.innerHTML = content;
    multipleFileUploadSuccess.style.display = "block";
});

function eliminar(objeto, index){
  //aquí agregas tu logica de eliminación
}
```

Un par de recomendaciones:

1. Cuando creas HTML a partir de string, es bueno ocupar [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (la comilla invertida), es más fácil que ir concatenando texto con un +
2. Tu tenías un each (que llama a rollCall) y un for al mismo arreglo. Yo los junté, ya que no tiene sentido recorrer lo mismo 2 veces seguidas

Comment: Si, muchas gracias es justo lo que necesitaba